# How does keeping a temperature probe still in an electric kettle affect its temperature readings?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, temperature

Greetings Physics Stack Exchange, I hope this question is adequate to this community as it is my first post.

For my physics lab report, I decided to measure the Specific Heat Capacity of NaCl at varying concentrations. I simply calculated the Specific Heat Capacity using the time/temperature values for each concentration. There may be an issue with the method that I need to specify in the evaluation of my results.

To carry on the experiment, I heated the different concentrations of NaCl through an electric kettle. I connected a temperature probe to my computer that has a data-logging software, and I was able to squeeze the temperature probe between the lid of the kettle, keeping the metal segment of the probe still at about half the depth of the NaCl concentration for the fixed amount of time that I decided as a control variable for this experiment.

When I presented my research paper for feedback, my teacher mentioned that to ensure the temperature measured was indeed the temperature of the solution, I was supposed to stir the solution continuously and if I did not do so, I would have to mention it in the evaluation of my experiment and data since the position of the probe in the kettle would seriously affect the temperature reading.

**What does that mean? Was I supposed to stir the solution for the whole time the electric kettle was heating it? To what extent would my temperature measures be worse if I kept the probe still in one place instead of stirring?**

Thanks in advance.